# Feature: grouping questions "sequentially" on mathoverflow or stackoverflow to create an "online course"

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Grouping questions "sequentially" on mathoverflow or stackoverflow by some criteria could allow use of XXXoverflow sites as an online university. Such a sequence would effectively become a curriculum for a given class.

So for example if we create a "sequence" on a particular topic starting from basic principles and moving on towards the more complex topics, there will be value in the sequence itself. Reader could start with inroductory questions, and may be ask something herself and then move on to more complex ones. Sequence probably could have a "predefined lacunas" when sequence creator was not able to find questions to answer a particular topic and they are now wanted.

Given the quality of content on stackoverflow such "courses" could become very helpful.

Edit: this of course could be implemented in a separate site or blog. But implementing this on StackOverflow would allow for reuse of excellent reputation system built on this site.

Comment: If this ever got implemented, I don't think I'd get **any** work done.

Comment: I'm envisioning a whole wave of "not an answer"'s on a whole new scale with this sort of thing.

Comment: We have this, but thought it most useful to go in the order that programming questions seem to come up.  So, just start with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1, and proceed from there...

Answer (score 8):

This wouldn't need to be a feature of StackOverflow for you to do this.  There is nothing stopping you from making, as an example, your own blog post in which you link to a series of StackOverflow posts, or even directly include a series of StackOverflow questions/answers in which you pick out those that you think would be most valuable to readers (assuming you link/attribute correctly as per the CC-wiki license).

Considering that this could so easily be done outside of the site itself (while still using SE's resources), and that it's rather divergent from SE's purpose (as a Q/A site rather than an online collage) it wouldn't make a whole lot of sense in my eyes to actually incorporate any special functionality into the site itself.

Comment: I think I like the "online collage" concept, but I'm not sure what it is :)

Comment: Agreed. The whole idea seems like a great re-use of the content that is generated here, but has nothing in particular to do with the structure of the sites.

Comment: That's good point. But there's one problem with implementing this on a different site: stackoverflow reputation system could not be reused there.

Comment: @fukanchik Why would it need to be?

Comment: @Servy, "courses" would be created by users in the same manner as questions.